# Decompiling my C# .exe with Red Gate reflector + Reflexil

Tags: c#, decompiler

I created a program in C# Visual Studio with framework 4.5, lost the project, but still have the .exe. I need a code within the .exe as I try to remake the project.

So I opened the exe in the reflector with the reflexil 'add-in' and I still can't work out how to see my code. This is all I see: http://gyazo.com/56dba4032dd57fe06947e0a9cef65f19

I need to be pointed in the right direction I'm not sure about this stuff.

Comment: Have you considered having a look at it in ILSpy>

Comment: Yes but it shows none of the code from the forms, I just get stuff like this: http://gyazo.com/4ff12a3fdbac3ffd21dfc8eefcba990f If I gave you the exe could you try it?

Comment: It's rather simple, contact the *real* owner of this code and ask for a source license.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your source was heavily obfuscated during or post compilation. I'm afraid it will take you a while to understand the source again.